# How to generate N random numbers in Python for lognormal and exponential distribution?

Tags: python, random, numbers

The value of  mean is 14 and std deviation is 1.4.When I tried with the formula random.lognormvariate(Mean,Sigma) , I get very large values.It doesnt look like to be correct. Is ther eany other way to generate N random numbers for Lognormal distribution.

Comment: What exactly are the results you are getting?  What exactly are the results you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` library for this purpose. It has a function for this purpose

```py
import numpy as np
...
np.random.lognormal(Mean, Sigma)
```

Read more about it [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is actually correct.

When you take the natural log of the normlog distributed value, you get the normal distributed value back:

```
import random as rd
from math import log
mean = 14
sigma = 1.4
rd_variable = rd.lognormvariate(mean, sigma)
print(log(rd_variable))
```